# Issues with axios POST requests (javascript) and Sinatra/Base API (ruby)

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, axios

I keep getting issues with attempting POST requests to my Ruby Sinatra/Base API using the javascript library axios

I have an example POST route in my Sinatra API below, axios keeps giving me generic errors

```
# Running on http://localhost:9292

class Endpoints < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::MultiRoute

  before do
    headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://localhost:8080',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST'],
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['Content-Type']
  end

  options '*' do
    headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://localhost:8080',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST'],
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['Content-Type']
  end

  route :post, :options, '/create' do
    # does something with params and return a JSON object
  end 
end
```

My Javascript Code using the axios library:

```
// Running on http://localhost:8080

axios.post('http://localhost:9292/create', {
  some_val: 'some value'
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

I keep getting a generic javascript error in my console

```
POST http://localhost:9292/create 403 (Forbidden)     bundle.js:20263
Error: Request failed with status code 403
  at createError (bundle.js:12159)
  at settle (bundle.js:19627)
  at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (bundle.js:11996)
```

my server side terminal doesnt give me anything better to work with, it says the options passed with a 200 status code, but gives me nothing as far as what caused the 403 error... no params make it successfully into my route...

```
::1 - - [08/May/2017:12:49:35 -0700] "OPTIONS /create HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0030
::1 - - [08/May/2017:12:49:35 -0700] "POST /create HTTP/1.1" 403 30 0.0076
```

Comment: Hi!, can you solved this? i have the same issue right now, and i donte get idiea how to solved :(

Comment: @Icaro i dont remember if I ever got this solved, I ended up abandoning Sinatra and learning Grape, its light years better than Sinatra and offers way better API features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, thank you, it works for me with this workaround:

```
before do
    if request.request_method == 'POST'
      body_parameters = request.body.read
      begin
        data= params.merge!(JSON.parse(body_parameters))
        @can_parse = true
      rescue
        puts "LOG: cant parse params" #TODO add real logger
        @can_parse = false
      end
    end
```